# Нужна ли вторая запятая в этом предложении?

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, нужна ли вторая запятая в предложении: "После этого продавец магазина подходит к тому, кто совершил кражу, и останавливает его". Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

*После этого продавец магазина подходит к тому, **кто совершил кражу**, и останавливает его.*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с местоименно-определительным **придаточным**, которое **обособляется двумя запятыми.**

Предикативная основа главного предложения: *продавец подходит и останавливает*.